# Data type mismatch in criteria expression TimeSerial column

Tags: ms-access, time, type-mismatch

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2k1B.png)

```
TRANSFORM Count(May18.ORDER_ID) AS CountOfORDER_ID
SELECT May18.DEPT
FROM [UPDATED POSITION] INNER JOIN May18 ON [UPDATED POSITION].DEPT = May18.DEPT
WHERE ((([UPDATED POSITION].SHIFT)="WEEKDAY_DAY") AND (((Weekday([INSTANT]))=1 Or (Weekday([INSTANT]))=7)=False) AND ((TimeSerial(Hour([Instant]),Minute([Instant]),0)) Between #12/30/1899 7:0:0# And #12/30/1899 15:0:0#))
GROUP BY May18.DEPT
PIVOT [UPDATED POSITION].POSITION;
```

The data I am using is for the month of May. I played around this is and the error is in the TimeSerial section. I tried to add the "Is Null" expression but I lost a lot of data that actually has info

Comment: `INSTANT` is a Date/Time field?

Comment: yes, it is date/time

Comment: Managed to see the image now - I take it `OrdersVerified` is also known as `May18`?

Comment: I also take it that `INSTANT` includes a date part and not just the time - you check the _WeekDay_ that `INSTANT` falls on.

Comment: yes it is, i'm not sure what I'm missing

Comment: in this case instant includes date and time

Comment: Most likely, your Instant contains Null values.

Comment: @Gustav what can I do to bypass the null values

Comment: You can include in the where clause: `And Instant Is Not Null`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're after this SQL:

```
TRANSFORM   COUNT(May18.ORDER_ID) AS CountOfOrderID
SELECT      May18.Dept
FROM        [UPDATED POSITION] INNER JOIN May18 ON [UPDATED POSITION].DEPT = May18.DEPT
WHERE       WEEKDAY(INSTANT,2)<6 AND TimeValue(Instant) BETWEEN #07:00:00# AND #15:00:00#
GROUP BY    May18.Dept
PIVOT   [UPDATED POSITION].POSITION
```

You have `Weekday([INSTANT]))=1 Or (Weekday([INSTANT]))=7)=False`.  This assumes the default that Sunday is day 1 and Saturday is day 7.  If you use `WEEKDAY(Instant,2)` it assumes that Monday is day 1 and Sunday is day 7 - so you just have to check if the day number is less than 6 to get a weekday.

The SQL also ignores the date.  To include it just add another clause to the `WHERE`:
 `AND DateValue(Instant) = #09/17/2018#` for 17th September or add a parameter:

```
PARAMETERS   MyDate DateTime;
TRANSFORM   COUNT(May18.ORDER_ID) AS CountOfOrderID
SELECT      May18.Dept
FROM        [UPDATED POSITION] INNER JOIN May18 ON [UPDATED POSITION].DEPT = May18.DEPT
WHERE       WEEKDAY(INSTANT,2)<6 AND 
            TimeValue(Instant) BETWEEN #07:00:00# AND #15:00:00# 
            AND DateValue(Instant) = MyDate
GROUP BY    May18.Dept
PIVOT   [UPDATED POSITION].POSITION
```

Comment: This did not help. Still having the same problem.

Comment: Could you post a sample of your data - it worked on the test data I was using, but had to make that up.